# Python default parameter assigning length of list

Tags: python, list, default-arguments

I get an error saying the arr for p2 is undefined. If I move the p2 = len(arr) - 1 expression into inside the function, the error goes away. Why do I get this error and how do I make this default argument expression work?

```
   def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = len(arr) -1):
NameError: name 'arr' is not defined
```

```
def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = len(arr) -1):
  while p1 < p2:
    if arr[p1] + arr[p2] == 0:
      return [arr[p1], arr[p2]]
    elif arr[p1] + arr[p2] < 0:
      p1 += 1
    else:
      p2 -= 1


print(sumZero_refactor([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([-2, 0, 1, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([1, 2, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([-8, -7, -5, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: `def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1=0, p2=None):
    p2 = p2 if p2 is not None else len(arr)`

Comment: Maybe the OP can clarify, but with respect to the other answers, I didn't get the impression that there's a need to pass a non-default value for ```p2```, merely that setting ```p2``` in the argument list was a convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages, like Ruby, allow a parameter list to reference previously named parameters. Unfortunately, Python does not.

You'll have to add `p2 = len(arr) - 1` inside the function body.

Comment: If I rewrite what I did in Javascript like function sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = arr.length - 1), this works with no problem. Python doesn't accept this I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the argument arr and then put arr for the p2 variable, since arr hasn't been fully defined yet.

Corrected code:

```
def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = None):
   if p2 is None:
     p2 = len(arr) - 1
   while p1 < p2:
     if arr[p1] + arr[p2] == 0:
       return [arr[p1], arr[p2]]
     elif arr[p1] + arr[p2] < 0:
       p1 += 1
     else:
       p2 -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = None):
  if p2 == None:
    p2 = len(arr) - 1
  while p1 < p2:
    if arr[p1] + arr[p2] == 0:
      return [arr[p1], arr[p2]]
    elif arr[p1] + arr[p2] < 0:
      p1 += 1
    else:
      p2 -= 1


print(sumZero_refactor([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([-2, 0, 1, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([1, 2, 3]))
print(sumZero_refactor([-8, -7, -5, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

This is because `arr` wasn't defined yet. Inside the function code, though, `arr` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You must define **arr** outside the parameter list that's where the real problem lies. Instead of finding the len of the arr inside parameter list, you can pass in the length of the arr along as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The Default parameters are executed from left to right when the function is defined only defined and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.

Even if you pass "arr" without the length function you would see the error as arr is
not defined during the function definition.

```
def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0, p2 = arr):
   pass
```

You can use "None" and explicitly test if the value is passed as an argument.

```
 def sumZero_refactor(arr, p1 = 0,p2 = None):
      if p2 is  None:
         p2 = len(arr) - 1
      while p1 < p2:
      if arr[p1] + arr[p2] == 0:
         return [arr[p1], arr[p2]]
      elif arr[p1] + arr[p2] < 0:
         p1 += 1
      else:
         p2 -= 1
```

Python reference - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions